# How do I stop the unity side bar from apearing when I try to drag & drop?

Tags: unity, drag-and-drop

Every time I use Drag&Drop (even with Bookmarks in Firefox or songs in Banshee) the unity side bar apears and often blocks the place where I want to drop it. Is there a way to fix this? 
EDIT: There is only one option for the launcher ( wether it appears when touching the side or the corner) but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Set the Launcher to always be below.

Answer (score 2):

In system settings under launcher and menus you can select "Show the launcher when the pointer touches the top left of the screen"

This will now mean you will not see the launcher until you move the mouse pointer to the top left.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you've solved this but I found it a bit annoying to. This may help for you or anyone else: 
http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-change-unity-sidebar-launcher-auto-hide-behaviour-in-ubuntu-11-04

may work for 11.10

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The launcher reveal on cursor grab & move (Drag & Drop) is a feature that is not user configurable

A bug request to make it an option got no traction, I don't believe there is any current intention to make it an user option