# Is there any way to stop Unity from lagging when I drag and drop URL's when using Firefox?

Tags: 11.10, unity, firefox, drag-and-drop

When using Firefox I often drag URLS's either to the address bar or search boxes. When I drag URL's the Unity launcher will appear and show which programs the URL can be dragged to. However this causes my system to briefly lag while the launcher sorts itself out. During this time I can't 'drop' the URL so am often left waiting for a couple of seconds which is a little frustrating. I have tried making the launcher always be present by following the answers to this question [How do I stop the unity side bar from apearing when I try to drag & drop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55212/how-do-i-stop-the-unity-side-bar-from-apearing-when-i-try-to-drag-drop) and using My Unity. but this hasn't stop the lag.

So is there a way to either:

a) Stop Unity from recognising that I'm dragging an URL and so stop the lag?

b) Is it possible that some animation setting is causing the lag and that I could turn it off? (I don't have any other noticeable lag at all when using Ubuntu in any other circumstances except this, so don't think it is my system being slow).

Any thoughts or possible solutions gratefully received, thanks for your time AskUbuntu-ers!

Comment: At the moment it appears that this a bug and so there is no answer. This is the launchpad report related to this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/772445

Comment: I feel your pain. I am doing a webpage that allows for in-page drag and drop, but Unity drag gets fired first, breaking everything. The best fix I've found, unfortunately, is using the latest version of Chrome.